# HotChocolate returns ignored field

Tags: c#, hotchocolate

I have a user object, where i have created an ObjectType to ignore the `Password` field as it is genearlly not a good idea to expose that in my API :) However HotChocolate still returns the password field in the response.

Account.cs

```
public class Account {
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(512)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 2)]
    // 0 = Landlord, 1 = Tenant, 2 = Maintenace
    public int AccountType { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public long CreatedMilliseconds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long UpdatedMilliseconds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long LastSeenMilliseconds { get; set; }
}

public class AccountType : ObjectType<Account>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Account> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Ignore(f => f.Password);
    }
}
```

AccountQuery.cs

```
[ExtendObjectType(typeof(Query))]
public class AccountQuery {
    private readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    
    [Authorize]
    public Account GetMe(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, [Service] DataContext context) {
        string userId = AuthHelper.GetUserId(claimsPrincipal);
        return context.Accounts.Where(x => userId == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

My program.cs

```
        // Add GraphQL services
        builder.Services
               .AddHttpContextAccessor()
               .AddDbContext<DataContext>()
               .AddGraphQLServer()
               .AddAuthorization()
               .AddQueryType<Query>()
               .AddMutationType<Mutations>()
               .AddTypeExtension<AccountMutations>()
               .AddTypeExtension<AccountQuery>();
```

Comment: Please tag this with the programming language you are using.

Comment: If you are not using the HotChocolate.Types.Analyzer Source Generator you have to register the ObjectType via .AddType<AccountType>().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[GraphQLIgnore]` attribute as described [here](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/defining-a-schema/interfaces).

```
[GraphQLIgnore]
public string Password { get; set; }
```